# Google Drive SDK: using drive.install scope to integrate web app into "open with" UI not working

Tags: google-drive-api

I have tried without much success to integrate my web application within the Google Drive UI (to open files). I cannot get the app to install using the OAuth scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install`.

I was wondering if anybody could share their Drive SDK configuration to see if I missed something. I tried installing my app using the Google API Console by selecting the **Drive Integration** to automatically authenticate. I also tried manually making the OAuth request using the `google-api-client` gem.

I always get the permissions dialog and I can see the following being requested: `Add itself to Google Drive`. I also get redirected back to my application like a normal OAuth request, but the application is never listed in Google Drive.

I have been requesting the following scopes:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
profile
user`

Allowing **Import** and these **Secondary MIME Types**:

`application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.html
text/html`

I followed the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/enable-sdk

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: When you say it is not listed in drive, do you mean that you can not see your app when selecting "open with"? or is not listed in the chrome webstore?

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo. I meant that it wasn't listed under "open with". I was able to solve this and provided an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by modifying my OAuth flow. It wasn't exchanging the authentication code for an access token before. Once I made it to that point everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was, that I didn't have this set:

> Allowing Import and these Secondary MIME Types:
>
> application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.html text/html

I'm working with Google Spreadsheets, so I need a mime type that a sheet can be converted to, such as `text/csv`, see https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app